# Meaning of the phrase "I am all ears"

Tags: meaning, phrases, metaphors

I was going through [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354379/how-to-measure-robustness) and I noticed this phrase.

> I am all ears

Is it some spelling error of "I am all yours" or does it mean something like "I am eager to listen"?

What is meant by this phrase & what do you call this type of phrase?

Comment: Definition of [be all ears](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ear?q=+all+ears#ear__9).

Comment: This question is a better fit for our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). Do check a dictionary first. [*All ears*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_ears), [*be all ears*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/be_all_ears).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a casual idiom that simply means "I am listening," or "I want to hear what you have to say."